# Why is Progressbar from react-bootstrap not working?

Tags: css, reactjs, progress-bar, react-bootstrap

I am using the ProgressBar from React bootstrap library, I don't know why it's not working properly
[image]

Here's the code

```
<div>
 <p>{selectedOption_1 ? <span><b>Your Choice</b> &#128073; &nbsp;</span> : null}  {props.location.state.option1}</p>
 <p style={{fontSize: "small"}}>Votes: {props.location.state.optionOneVotes}  </p>
 <ProgressBar now={optionOnePercentage} animated variant="warning" striped label={`${optionOnePercentage}%`} />
 </div>
```

Even if I pass hardcoded value, the result is same

```
<ProgressBar now={60} />
<ProgressBar now='60' animated variant="warning"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

try passing a constant value and test it to see if it works

the problem might be that you are trying to pass `optionOnePercentage` from props or state and you have forgotten to write it

Since there isnt much of the code problem can be anywhere

## EDIT 1

try including

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
```

in `index.js` file if  you have created the app using `npx create-react-app`

Comment: I have edited my question , I hope it is cleared now

Comment: have you imported the bootstrap file ? i tried your code it didn't show the progress bar, then i installed 'bootstrap' and included it in index.js it worked

Comment: Yes, I have already added this line in the index.js but the problem still exists.
If you open the picture that I have attached, Upper bar is at 0, Lower progress bar is at 100% you can see a very little yellow line on the top, I don't know why it is behaving so